# How to access a public bitbucket repo via jitpack.io?

Tags: bitbucket, jitpack

I'd like to use the latest version code from the public [bitbucket project rxlint](https://bitbucket.org/littlerobots/rxlint) in my gradle project. But I don't know which URL to use.

I've tried to enter some URLs (see below) on https://jitpack.io/ - without success. The error message is always:

```
Repo not found or no access token provided
```

and since this repo is public, I guess, that I am just using the wrong format for the URL

URL's I've tried without success:

- org.bitbucket.littlerobots/rxlint
- https://bitbucket.org/littlerobots/rxlint
- https://bitbucket.org/littlerobots/rxlint/src
- git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/littlerobots/rxlint.git
- V1.2 tag: https://bitbucket.org/littlerobots/rxlint/src/a5e5d85b8358f74b33f5844ff154c80bc10d0009/?at=v1.2
- tip tag: https://bitbucket.org/littlerobots/rxlint/src/462cbb708d8897480fc327e736acde50377b4e2c/?at=tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That project is hosted as a Mercurial (hg) repository on Bitbucket. JitPack only supports Git repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create authToken for this repository:

https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/#bitbucket

In order to Look Up and manage Bitbucket repositories you should add the App Password to your JitPack account:

1. Sign In on https://jitpack.io
2. Click on your username (https://jitpack.io/w/user)
3. Enter your Bibucket user and App Password